# Initializing referenced objects in entity framework unit of work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work

I have a class in Entity framework 5 (using MVC 4):

```
public class JobFunction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string JobFunctionName { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public Status JFStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In my OnModelCreating method, I establish a FK relationship with the Status table as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobFunction>().HasRequired(a => a.JFStatus).
                WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.StatusId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

In my controller, I get a list of JobFunction objects as follows:

```
List<JobFunction> jfList = uow.JobFunctionRepository.GetAll().ToList<Catalog>();
```

where uow is my Unit of Work object, and JobFunctionRepository is defined. When I examine any JobFunction object in jfList, I see the following in my watch window:

Id: 1
JfStatus: null
JobFunctionName: "Manager"
StatusId: 2

Note that JFStatus is null. My question is: what provisions do I make in my code to initialize JFStatus to the appropriate Status object (based on the value of StatusId), during my GetAll call?

Thanks in advance.
-Zawar

Answer (score 0):

You need some instrument to apply eager loading when you load the data through your repository. For example you could give your `GetAll` method a parameter list of expressions for the navigation properties you want to include in your query:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
//...

public IQueryable<JobFunction> GetAll(
    params Expression<Func<JobFunction, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<JobFunction> query = context.JobFunctions;

    foreach (var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);

    return query;
}
```

Then you call it like so:

```
List<JobFunction> jfList = uow.JobFunctionRepository
    .GetAll(jf => jf.JFStatus)
    .ToList();
```

The `JFStatus` property should be filled now.